Uncaught Runtime Error After Successful React Project Build
I've successfully built my React project, but I'm encountering an Uncaught runtime error when running the application. The build process completes without errors, but upon starting the app, this runtime issue emerges.
Here are the details:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'indexOf')
    at ut.fromString (index.esm2017.js:1032:1)
    at gh (index.esm2017.js:17952:1)
    at Layout.js:377:1
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Array.<anonymous> (Layout.js:373:1)
    at next (index.esm2017.js:20677:1)
    at index.esm2017.js:16739:1

useEffect(() => {
    if (localStorage.getItem("userdata")) {
        setUserRole(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userdata")).role);
    }
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(collection(db, "supportRoom"), (snapshot) => {
        if (snapshot.docs.length == 0) {
            setHelpCall(false);
            setHelpCaller({});
        } else {
            const allData = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
                id: doc.id,
                ...doc.data(),
            }));
            allData.forEach((docs) => {
                if (docs.response == false && docs.reciever == "") {
                    setSupportRoomData(supportRoomData);
                    setHelpCall(true);
                    const docRef = doc(db, "users", docs.creater);
                    getDoc(docRef).then((doc) => {
                        setHelpCaller(doc.data());
                        setHelpCallerId(doc.id);
                    });
                } else {
                    setHelpCall(false);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    return () => {
        // cancelHelpCall()
        unsubscribe();
    };
}, [userData]);

I have already tried to check data fetch from firebase, clearing the cache, resinstalling dependencies, but the issue persists.
Has anyone encountered a similar problem or have any suggestions for resolving this runtime error?
Thank you in advance for your help!

You must study the cases in which the "fromString" func return null, then the input from the array which caused error. Use console.log, try catch perhap

In this line const docRef = doc(db, "users", docs.creater) you should check what the value of docs.creater is when the error occurs.  It would also be helpful to confirm which is line 373, 377 of layout.js (I guess that 377 is the line I mentioned)

Hi @James, thank you for your comment. You're right
const docRef = doc(db, "users", docs.creater);
This is the line 377. And I tried to log it but it's not triggered.
console.log(docRef, "this is a doc ref");

@James FYI, userData=null, userRole=undefined. and I logged allData.
I found this inside allData array. creater=null

Sorry I can’t provide more insight than “don’t pass null” to that function.
